# Ruby on Rails Plugin: acts_as_taggable_on_steroids. Keep getting "method_missing" undefined local variable or method 'acts_as_taggble_on'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, method-missing, acts-as-taggable-on-ster

I am trying to implement a tagging system for my rails app. I employed the popular plugin acts_as_taggable_on_steroids, and followed the instruction on how to install it. I then included acts_as_taggable in the model that I would like to have tags on, but then when I try to start the server I keep getting the error `method_missing': undefined local variable or method`acts_as_taggable' for # (NameError)

I look on google and the author suggested to try acts_as_taggable_on, but still this did not fix the problem. I am struggling on this problem for hours already, but still don't know where is the problem. Could anyone please shed some light?

Thank you very much for all the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to require the lib ruby of act as taggable on steroids at the beginning of your file?

Something like:

```
require 'acts_as_taggable'
```

maybe?

Comment: At the top of your ruby file using the acts_as_taggable gem =)